# Need to create a chat bubble like Whatsapp with two labels on top of the message in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, chat

I'm trying to create a chat bubble like this:
[Actual Bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxMY2.png)
[Actual Bubble 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRdJH.png)
This is what I have been able to achieve so far.
[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abrmd.png)
[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW4te.png)

This is my code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestingView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            /// header
            VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                HStack {
                    HStack() {
                        Text("abcd")
    
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("~abcd")
                    }
                }.padding([.trailing, .leading], 15)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                /// text
                HStack {
                    Text("Hello Everyone, bdhjewbdwebdjewbfguywegfuwyefuyewvfyeuwfvwbcvuwe!")
                    
                }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 15)
                
                /// timestamp
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("12:00 PM")
                }.padding(.trailing,15)
                
            }.background(Color.gray)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
                .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: .leading)
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct TestingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestingView()
    }
}
```

The main goal is that I want the two labels on top to be distant relative to the size of the message content. I am not able to separate the two labels far apart i.e one should be on the leading edge of the bubble and the other one on the trailing edge.

Already tried spacer, it pushes them to the very edge, we need to apart them relative to the content size of the message as shown in attached images.

Comment: Already tried spacer, it pushes them to the very edge, we need to apart them relative to the content size of the message as shown in attached images.

Comment: I tried adding spacer in between two HStack and this is how it looks: https://imgur.com/OqKZPGQ is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified code.

Regarding Spacer: To achieve your desired result you put both Text views inside of a HStack, and put a Spacer between them. So the Spacer pushes them apart to the leading and trailing edge.

Also I recommend to only use one padding on the surrounding stack.

[image]

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // header
            HStack {
                Text("+123456")
                    .bold()
                Spacer() // Spacer here!
                Text("~abcd")
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            
            // text
            Text("Hello Everyone, bdhjewbdwebdjewbfguywegfuwyefuyewvfyeuwfvwbcvuwe!")
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            
            // timestamp
            Text("12:00 PM")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: .leading)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can put that header into overlay of main text, so it will be always aligned by size of related view, and then it is safe to add spacer, `cause it do not push label wider than main text.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo1][image: demo2]

```
var body: some View {
    let padding: CGFloat = 15
    ZStack {
        /// header
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            /// text
            HStack {
                //Text("Hello Everyone")   // short test
                Text("Hello Everyone, bdhjewbdwebdjewbfguywegfuwyefuyewvfyeuwfvwbcvuwe!") // long test
            }
            .padding(.top, padding * 2)
            .overlay(
                HStack {            // << here !!
                    HStack() {
                        Text("abcd")

                    }
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Text("~abcd")
                    }
                }
            , alignment: .top)
            .padding([.trailing, .leading], padding)

            /// timestamp
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("12:00 PM")
            }.padding(.trailing, padding)

        }.background(Color.gray)
            .padding(.leading, padding)
            .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

Comment: Text is overlapping when there is less space between them. Check here [https://i.postimg.cc/d05wt9dm/Screenshot-2022-07-18-at-11-19-51-AM.png]

Answer (score -1):

To separate two components with fairly space in the middle, use HStack{} with Spacer().

This is a sample approach for this case. Code is below the image:
[image]

```
VStack {
  HStack {
    Text("+92 301 8226")
        .foregroundColor(.red)
    Spacer()
    Text("~Usman")
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
  }
  .padding(.bottom, 5)
  .padding(.horizontal, 5)
  Text("Testing testingtesting testing testing testingtesting testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing.")
    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
  HStack {
    Spacer()
    Text("2:57 AM")
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .font(.subheadline)
  }
  .padding(.trailing, 5)
}
.frame(width: 300, height: 160)
.background(.white)
.cornerRadius(15)
```